# Outlook calendar event view from inbox

Tags: view, outlook

[image]

Hello,

I have a question regarding the view of event in outlook (2016) in the email area (inbox or sent items).

As you can see in the attached picture, the "when" part is showing the date, but not showing the week day.

How can i fix it to show the day as well, and not only the date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. found it. 
it is the windows setting for date and time.

So in windows setting need to select the option of dddd dd/mm/yyyy for long date to fix this issue.